# XCode: Reload UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell subclass with labels, indicator views, etc. I need it to update as data is retrieved from the web (specifically I have a label for number of results).

I used this to try and reload the cells, but it doesn't work. I know that cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called, and the value that the data source itself is updated.

```
[self.myFriendsTbl beginUpdates];
[self.myFriendsTbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.myFriendsTbl] endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.myFriendsTbl reloadData];
```

This will force each visible `UITableViewCell` to be reloaded. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.myFriendsTbl reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call beginUpdates or endUpdates since you are not deleting or inserting cells.

Just change the data for the specific row in the DataSource and call

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

as you were doing.

If it doesn't work maybe you are not changing the correct row or you are indexPath is not the right one. Show some more code to check that. Using some kind of animation like "UITableViewRowAnimationLeft", for example, will help you see which cell is being changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should mention that it does change some of the time, but not all of the time which is what is confusing me. The index path is therefore correct (and I debugged to check..just threw in an NSLog for the cell text in cellForRowAtIndexPath). Is it possible that I'm just changing it too often and its conflicting? My 'web receiver' methods are asynchronous so they could be calling the reload at around the same time? Is there away around that (if you think thats the problem)?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to update the cell before the DataSource has actually changed? Insert some more NSLogs to look for that.

Comment: I did, the data source has changed. Directly above the line where I say [tableView lblTotalPhotos] setText:newNumber] I NSLogged newNumber.  I'm confused :(